# Laravel 10 test symfony message object

Tags: laravel, symfony, email, testing, laravel-10

I changed email MessageId in laravel with function

```
$this->withSymfonyMessage(function (Email $message){
    $message->getHeaders()->addIdHeader('Message-ID', 'mymessageid@domain.com');        
});
```

I try to write test in laravel, that will check if sent email message has correct MessageID. And i cant access Symfony\Component\Mime\Email Object in callback for Mail::assertSent function.

Does anyone have idea, how can i catch Symfony\Component\Mime\Email instance in laravel tests when Message was sent? If i had this instance, i can get message Id in many ways...

Comment: Based on what I checked, it is very hard to test what you want to test. You would need to mock the `Mailer` (driver, sort of) and get in the middle and stuff, but it is honestly very hard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.